# Dropbox.com as backup system for my Ubuntu

Tags: backup, dropbox, online-backup

Can I have multple drop boxes (dropbox.com) or Ubuntu One accounts on a single machine (Ubuntu 9.04 or 10.04) to backup multiple projects ?

Comment: To backup multiple projects you don't need multiple accounts, you need a larger storage for them.

Comment: @Lipis Obviously I'm trying to find a free solution.

Comment: For your projects you could also use https://bitbucket.org which has unlimited storage and it's for free. But for automatic sync I'm afraid that you will have to pay something. It's too expensive to built and support something like that for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though there are some [workarounds](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/MultipleInstancesOnUnix) it's strongly not recommended, because either of these services were designed to handle that. Also if it's used to get some extra quota it's against Dropbox's ToS and I'm pretty sure that it is against the Ubuntu One's as well.

Here is what a [Dropbox dude](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=28067#post-179250) (N.N.) said on this matter:

> HELLo!
>
> Note that in the vast majority of cases where people are asking about multiple accounts is best solved by Shared Folders. Unless there are two different people using the same computer, which different OS accounts is the proper way of handling it.
>
> Third party applications and hacks that are designed to get multiple Dropbox instances running at the same time for one user is not recommended, not only because they are completely unsupported (by the Dropbox team at least), but also because Dropbox is not meant to be utilized in such a manner. So the chance of issues is a lot higher than running Dropbox as per normal.
>
> PS: Also, please keep in mind that using multiple Dropbox accounts to circumvent our quota limitations is against our ToS.
>
> Happy syncin'!